# Find Value in Multidimensional Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to dynamically find a particular value inside a multi dimensional object.

To create the object, I'm doing this:

```
var inViewElements = {};

$('.story-section')
    .each(
        function(index){

            var sectionId = 'story-section-' + Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

            $(this).attr('id', sectionId);

            var inViewHeight = $(this).height(),
                inViewPosTop = $('#' + sectionId).offset().top,
                inViewPosBottom = ((inViewPosTop + inViewHeight) - (inViewTolerence + inViewHeight));

            inViewElements[inViewPosTop] = {
                id: sectionId,
                height: inViewHeight,
                bottom: inViewPosBottom
            }; 

            debug('Inview', 'Object', sectionId);                                       
            debug('Inview', 'Height', inViewHeight);
            debug('Inview', 'Offset Top', inViewPosTop);
            debug('Inview', 'Offset Bottom', inViewPosBottom);

        }
    );

console.log(inViewElements);
```

And the output looks like:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is compare if another variable value, for example:

```
var currentPos = '3038';
```

Matches any of the objects keys. E.g. the 3038 or 2038 etc.

I'm struggling to figure this one out!

Comment: `inViewElements[currentPos]`?

Comment: This is not multidimensional anything. You have an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to search for an object that contains a certain value?

There is no way to query an array/object in Javascript. As you're not using incremental indexes, I would suggest using a foreach loop, using a conditional statement to check whether the property you're trying to match is equal to the value you're looking for.

It would be quicker to use a for loop, however that would require incremental indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you r logging response variable through which ur output came then u can use this function

```
for(var x in response){
    if( x == 3038) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

or

```
for(var x in response){
    if(x == currentPos){
         //dosomething
    }
 }
```

can u give me the proper code of how u put values to console log so i will edit the answer properly accourding to your question

Comment: I've updated the original question with the full code. What I'm trying to do is compare the scroll offset position from the to of the page, to a value in the object. If this matches any then it will run a function.